# What does Connection attempt from disallowed node mean?

Tags: erlang

What happen when you see the following error message in the Erlang VM?

```erlang
** Connection attempt from disallowed node name@name.com **
```

Is it about when we do not set cookies for two nodes or when we set different cookies for two nodes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because both nodes don't have the same cookie. Start both nodes with the same cookie and check that the cookie on both nodes are identical using

```
erlang:get_cookie().
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case in windows 10, I have changed and kept the value same in the below two files and restart the RabbitMQ service. It resolved my issue.

1. C:\Windows.erlang.cookie
2. C:\Users%USERNAME%.erlang.cookie